# Swift iOS, CLLocationManager didUpdateLocations recording unvisited locations

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

In my GPS app written in Swift 3 on XCode8 for iOS, CLLocationManager didUpdateLocations is being called fine, but I am finding it is often accepting locations I haven't visited (tested in iOS 9)

Below is a picture of an MKMapView I have set up with the relevant recorded locations

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7UIS.jpg

- Red Dot = Start (travelling north)
- Blue Dot = Finish (after returning along same path I travelled north)
- Green Dots = Never travelled this far south

NB: I was driving when I recorded this, not running. Not sure if this matters

So on my way home I turn from near the red dot into my house where the blue dot is, I never travel south of my house.
I am wondering why CLLocationManager recorder locations at the green dots when I didn't travel this far south (I have recorded this path multiple times and this keeps happening, maybe it is assuming I am reaching the intersection 70m away?)

I am graphing my distance covered vs duration and velocity vs distance covered, so I am seeing spikes at the end of these too because in the short time I turn into my house, CLLocationManager has assumed I have moved to the intersection at the bottom green dot and back again and included all this distance.

I have tried changing distanceFilter and horizontalAccuracy but this hasn't fixed the problem. From what I have read online I am guessing I may need to smooth my data somehow or filter out unrealistic accelerations but I am not sure how I would implement this.

Below is the relevant code for my CLLocationManager. Any help on how to fix this would be great, thanks!

```
var distance = 0.0
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!



lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
    var _locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    _locationManager.delegate = self
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    _locationManager.activityType = .fitness
    _locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0
    return _locationManager}()
lazy var locations = [CLLocation]()



extension GPSTracker: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    for location in locations {
        let howRecent = location.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow
        let accuracy = location.horizontalAccuracy
        if abs(howRecent) < 10 && accuracy < 10 && accuracy > 0 && location.verticalAccuracy > 0 {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 500, 500)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            if self.locations.count > 0 {
                    distance += location.distance(from: self.locations.last!)
                    var coords = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
                    coords.append(self.locations.last!.coordinate)
                    coords.append(location.coordinate)
                    mapView.add(MKPolyline(coordinates: &coords, count: coords.count))}
            self.locations.append(location)}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The iOS GPS is, to put it bluntly, squirrely. It gives spurious readings sometimes. You have to teach your app to filter out the bad readings.

You should check the "horizontal accuracy" reading on each location update you get. That is a "radius of confusion" value, in meters. The **real** location can be anywhere inside a circle with that radius. So if the value is 500, it means that your real location could be anywhere inside a circle with a radius of 500 meters, or anywhere in a circle with a circumfrence of a kilometer.

When the satellite signals get weak the quality of the GPS readings goes down (strangely, a larger "horizontal accuracy" value means a worse GPS reading.) You need to decide what your tolerance for bad GPS signals is, and reject readings poorer than your tolerance. At that point you should display a "weak GPS signal" message to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your response Duncan, I have tracked the horizontalAccuracy on this drive again and i've been accepting anything between 0 and 10m, so does that mean it should be accurate +/- 10m radius? It is interesting because the green dot on the intersection is 80m away (from google maps)